# How lambda expression initialize parameter?

Tags: java, lambda, parameters, initialization

I'm confused with lamda expression.

```
JavaDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rsvpsWithGuestsStream =
        meetupStream.filter(f -> !f.value().contains("\"guests\":0"));

rsvpsWithGuestsStream.foreachRDD((JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> r) -> {        
    MongoSpark.save(
            r.map(
                e -> Document.parse(e.value())
            )
    );            
});
```

Here is a foreachRDD method `void foreachRDD(VoidFunction<R> foreachFunc)`, It accepts a functional interface.

And in code, `JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> r` passed as a argument which is internally used by its `call` method.

I want to know Does lambda expression initialize `r` on its own ? Becasue it can call `map` only if its initialized.  And In code I cant see anywhere its already created.

Can anyone help me to understand this ?

Comment: It's pretty much got to be created by the implementation of the `forEachRDD` method.

Comment: You can consider a lambda expression `param -> { someCall(param); }` as an anonymous mehod `void anonymous(Object param) { someCall(param); }`. The `foreachRDD` method calls this anonymous method with an argument.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression does not initialize anything. It is just an anonymous function which does something with its arguments - assuming they have been already initialized. I am not familiar with your use case (guess it is Spark) but it looks like r is just one of the elements in the stream, and each such element is passed in to your lambda. Below is a similar but much simpler example:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c").forEach(el -> System.out.println(el));
```

Here el is each of the elements "a", "b" and "c", passed in to the lambda which simply prints it. Just like a function, a lambda doesn't know anything about its arguments and whether they are initialiazed - this is up to the caller, in the above cases - the forEach methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from Java spec:

> 15.27.1. Lambda Parameters
>
> When the lambda expression is invoked (via a method invocation
> expression (§15.12)), the values of the actual argument expressions
> **initialize** newly created parameter variables, each of the declared or inferred type, before execution of the lambda body. The Identifier
> that appears in the LambdaParameter or directly in the
> LambdaParameterList or LambdaParameters may be used as a simple name
> in the lambda body to refer to the formal parameter.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.1